# Why ordering in SQLite table taking more space?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I had table 'r_ele'. Database's size was 42MB.
I copied it by ordering its value to 'r_ele_new' table. Database's size is 50MB.
Then deleted old 'r_ele' table. But size is staying in same level(50MB).
Why its size becoming bigger? Is it because of ordering?

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your new table has more columns than the old table.

Anyway, to remove free pages from a database file, execute [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html).
However, this makes sense only if you are not going to fill the database with more data later.